# how do I handle modal dialogs with selenium 2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a link that opens a modal dialog

How can Selenium 2 handle this.

Thanks

Aidan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With selenium 2 , I'm able to select elements in a jquery modal dialog using the normal "findElement" method.

e.g. the following code in c#

```
[Test]
    public void DialogBox()
    {
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.nemikor.com/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/");
        // open modal dialog
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("opener")).Click();
        // click a button on the modal dialog.
        driver.FindElementByClassName("ui-icon ui-icon-closethick").Click();

    }
```

Comment: jquery modal dialog is a Div on same page. not same as window modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

This feature to handle modal dialog is not shipped yet into webdriver until the last release 2.0b3 ([link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284)).
Eagerly waiting for the next version to become public soon.(Test Environment: `C#, Webdriver 2.0b3 and Nunit`).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some known issues on this http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284 but a possible solution given [at this link](http://seleniumdeal.blogspot.com/2010/04/working-with-modal-dialogs-and-selenium.html)

Comment: Just little note (for people who came from search engines) that mentioned issue 284 is still with status "New" it actually partial fixed and should work in most cases for IE driver (details on issue comments which I was ignoring at first due issue status..).